# How to allocate memory for RegGetValueW (via the Windows crate for Rust)

Tags: windows, rust

I'm attempting to read a value from the windows registry using the official [windows rust bindings](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/bindings/Windows/Win32/System/Registry/fn.RegGetValueW.html).

I've tried a lot of different things without success, so I created a C++ version as a sanity test:

```c
WCHAR value[64];
PVOID pvData = value;
DWORD size = sizeof(value);

LSTATUS result = RegGetValue(
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
    L"SOFTWARE\\MyTest\\foo",
    NULL,
    RRF_RT_REG_SZ,
    NULL,
    pvData,
    &size);

if (result == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    wprintf(L"Value data: %s (%d)\n", (PWSTR)pvData, size);
}
```

This works as expected and prints `Value data: hello (12)` (It's not perfect but the end result shows at least a working happy path with no cleanup.)

My latest Rust attempt is:

```rust
unsafe {
  
    let mut value: Vec<u16> = vec![0; 64];

    let mut my_size: u32 = 0;
    let size = &mut my_size as *mut u32;

    let result = RegGetValueW(
        HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
        "SOFTWARE\\MyTest\\foo",
        None,
        RRF_RT_REG_SZ,
        std::ptr::null_mut(), // Doesn't allow None
        value.as_mut_ptr() as *mut c_void,
        size
    );

    println!("Result: {:?}", result);
    println!("Value data: {:?} ({:?})", value, *size);
    // Result: LSTATUS(234)         // 234 = ERROR_MORE_DATA, so pvData is not large enough
    // Value data: [0, 0, ...] (14) // 14 is peculiar given the C++ size reports 12
}
```

Would greatly appreciate some guidance or nudge in the right direction!

Comment: If you want to put a buffer on the heap, `Vec` is the way to go. Unless you are doing something more complex like creating a dynamically sized type, you should not need to use Layout or `std::alloc`. `let mut value: vec<u8> = vec![0; 64];` Then you can get a pointer to the first element with `value.as_mut_ptr() as *mut c_void`. However, I often prefer using `value.as_mut_ptr() as *mut _` to let the compiler fill in the type since its a bit shorter and conveys the same general message.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you are getting the error though. It probably means that the `windows` crate is doing something strange. I'm guessing you already know, but you can always use the `winapi` crate for rust bindings straight into the original C++ version. https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.9/winapi/um/winreg/fn.RegGetValueW.html I don't know much about `windows`, but based on the mix of rust and C types I am guessing that the interface is not completely finished yet.

Comment: Thanks @Locke, the Vec approach does look like a cleaner solution, though oddly enough it results in the same result from the API and the contents are all 0s. I'm hoping to use the official Windows crate (there are a few other options for the Registry too) as there are likely some other APIs from it I'll need to use at some point in the future but appreciate the suggestion. I may raise this issue on the Github project unless someone points out something I'm doing wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: The rust [implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/blob/115d0d07dd3ec23ccfb03bd188e770b10d280d25/src/Windows/Win32/System/Registry/mod.rs#L1908) of that function is just strange. They transmute every type before calling the C++ version despite none of the transmutes changing the types of the data. The only changes it makes before passing it to the base function are on the first 3 arguments. My guess is it may not be adding a null character to the end of the string. Try explicitly null terminating the string `"SOFTWARE\\MyTest\\foo\0"`.

Comment: I see the same result from switching the path to `"SOFTWARE\\MyTest\\foo\0"` I should also note that I was able to use `RegCreateKeyExW` to create the key using the same path without appending `\0` (just as an additional data point)

Comment: I think I found your problem. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/extensible-storage-engine/wchar. `WCHAR` would be a `u16` in rust, meaning the buffer you pass in the rust version is half the size of the one in the C++ code. It also makes me wonder if anything else should be in utf16 here.

Comment: That is true! I lost that change somewhere along the way. I'm going to update my original comment to use the Vec and a u16 but sadly I see the same results with the u16 (tested with both the array and Vec methods) :(

Comment: When you tested with `u16`, did you also change the size passed accordingly? `let mut my_size = (std::mem::size_of::<u16>() * value.len()) as u32;`.

Comment: I did not! That did it! Thanks Locke! You should add that as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: I feel like its worth noting (because it seems very bizarre) that RegGetValueW still fails on any Windows Server OS I've tried (including Server 2016 and 2019 on Github actions) Still trying to make sense of why that could be but its intriguing as every Windows 10 machine I've tried has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had two major issues that needed to be resolved:

> WCHAR would be a u16 in rust

I was using `u8`

```rust
let mut value: Vec<u16> = vec![0; 64];
```

> When using `u16` I also needed to change the size passed to `RegGetValueW`

```rust
let mut my_size = (std::mem::size_of::<u16>() * value.len()) as u32;
```